# Multiple Google accounts for multiple services of Google

Tags: google-account

If one has multiple different Gmail accounts not linked to each other, is it allowed to use one account for, say, Adwords as a seller and buyer, the other - for other Google services, the other -- yet for some other service and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't require users to reveal their identity to allow them to use most of their services, they just have some controls in place to prevent abuse.

In services like AdWords you could use an email address that will be identified as the Adwords account owner and add other accounts to allow them to do some tasks.

Bear in mind that not all services allow to change the account used as owner or to transfer/export/merge the account assets so in some cases could be  convenient to have an specific account to manage that kind of services.

References

- [Create an AdWords account: How to sign up](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6366720?hl=en)